# Programming languages that feature shorthand equality logic, for comparing one variable to multiple

Tags: programming-languages, equality

I'd be interested to know whether there are programming languages which have "shorthand equality constructs" (I just made that term up, but not sure how to describe it).

So rather than the normal:

> if (X == 1 || X == 2)

A kind-of shorthand equality check, like this: ?

> if (X == 1 || 2)

I understand that there are many for & againsts for this sort of construct. And that I can create functions to do something similar, but I'd be interested whether there are languages that enable you to do out of the box.

---

EDIT

Thanks Michael for helping me clarify things, I like the way Python does it.

I'll try and explain better, as looking at my question above it doesn't explain very well.

Rather than checking for something within a collection, or creates a collection in the background.

I'm wondering if there are programming languages that when only defining the left hand variable once, it will automatically create the left and right for you.

So writing this:

if (X == 1 || 2 || 3)

Would actually create

if (X == 1 || X == 2 || X == 3)

I realise this pseudo synatx isn't hugely useful and that creating the collection is a fine way of doing it. But wondered if it exists anywhere.

Comment: So the test needs to also be short-circuiting?

Comment: @Michael, yeah thinking about it, the test would be short-circuted. I suppose I'm wondering whether there are languages that feature a shorthand "if".

Comment: @AlexKey - The conditional operator is a shorthand `if`. In fact you can use it to write very cryptic (but beautiful) if else conditions: http://jsfiddle.net/QFh4C/1/

Comment: @AlexKey - Your syntax for set membership results in ambiguous grammar. Does `X == 1 || 2` expand to `X == 1 || X == 2` as you want it to, or does it expand to `X == true` as I expect the logical or operator (`||`) would do in most programming languages.

Comment: Hi @AaditMShah, so I wondering if there are any languages that would expand a construct to X == 1 || X == 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of anything with that syntax, but it is closely related to testing for set membership, which many languages do include, either as a language construct or in a library.

For example, consider this bit of Python:

```
x = 1
if x in {1, 2}:
    #do something
```

That works in Python 2.7+, where there is syntax for set literals. Earlier versions of Python would construct the set as:

```
x = 1
if x in set([1, 2]):
    #do something
```

Apart from the syntactic difference, the above set-based approach also differs in that all the possible values are eagerly evaluated. You couldn't, for example, do this:

```
x = 1
if x in {1, 2/0}:
    #do something
```

You'd get an error for dividing by zero.

Comment: Thanks Michael. Do you mean checking whether X is in array or list? Is there a way of doing it against literal single variables?

Comment: @Alex Key Do the examples clarify things?

Comment: Thanks Michael for the examples. From what I understand of python, the curly braces and set keyword are creating a kind-of-like an array / list structure and seeing if X is in there?

Comment: @Alex Key It is creating a set object, implemented using a hash table. It differs from an array or list in that its elements are unordered and that it offers `O(1)` testing for membership in the set. More important than a particular implementation is the mathematical notion of set---a collection of values which allows testing for membership.

Comment: Thanks Michael, it looks like a handy implementation. I've updated my question a little bit to help clarify as I don't think I explained very well.

Comment: While this answer is technically correct, it omits the use of lists and tuples (and any other collection, for that matter) on which the `in` keyword can operate. +1 regardless.

Comment: @Walter It's not really an answer about what Python supports, though, but about sets as being similar to what the OP asked about. Looking at the comments, in particular, I can see how it might look like I was saying sets must be used for this in Python; as you point out, there are other options, including rolling your own collection that supports membership testing.

Answer (score 2):

Bourne shell:

```
case $x in one | 2 | thr33 | f0re) echo less than six;; esac  # spot logic error
```

Comment: Thanks @tripleee, I'm not to familar with bourne scripts... Will that create a collection out of "one | 2 | thr33 | f0re" ? And loop over it? Or will it genearte a set equality checks?

Comment: @Alex Key: the condition is true if the variable `$x` is either `one` or `2` or `thr33` or `f0re`.  All of this is strictly strings.  I guess internally it is converted into an array of strings, and a loop is run until there is a match, or all items have been compared.

Comment: Oh, and there's support for glob-type wildcard; `case $1 in *.*) there is a dot in the string ;; esac`

Comment: Interesting, it's an answer from another angle to my question. It creates the loop in the background so not quite shorthand to the classic "=", but accomplishes the same thing... a handy syntax to have. +1 from me.

Comment: sql does the same too: `where x in (1, 2, 3)` ! :)